# is the following set closed under addition and multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

Decide whether $S $ is a subring of $ R $ in the following case:

$R=\mathbb{Q} $ und $ S= $ { $ \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $ b $  is not divisible by 5  }

Approach:

1. $ S $ is a subgroup of $ (R,+) $ :

- Since 0 is a rational number and $ b $ is not divisible by 5 for any $ \frac{a}{b} \in S $, we have $ \frac{0}{1} \in S $.
- For any $ \frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \in S $, their sum $ \frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a d+b c}{b d} $ is also in $ S $ because the denominator $ b d $ is not divisible by 5 .

2. $ S $ is closed under multiplication:

- For any $ \frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \in S $, their product $ \frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d}=\frac{a c}{b d} $ is in $ S $ because  $ b d $ is not divisible by 5 .

Comment: The one problem I see is in defining $S$: if you take $\frac{a}{b} \in S$ and multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $5$, you get that $\frac{5a}{5b}$ belongs in $S$, with $5b$ being divisible by $5$, so you need to enforce that $a$ and $b$ be coprime to have a well-defined set. Otherwise I do not see any issue inherent to the proof itself.

Comment: do you mean, redefine \( S \) as follows:
 $ S= $ { $ \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $ and gcd(a,b) = 1 $ b $  is not divisible by 5  }

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Comment: I think the definition is fine, it doesn't insist that $5a/5b \notin S$.

Comment: @ronno Right, I should have paid more attention. But to be fair the definition I proposed is in retrospect equivalent to the one given here, so at least I wasn't totally off either. Either way there was gonna be an issue in terms of choosing a representative, as you pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written down has most of the correct ingredients. A somewhat subtle point about well-definedness and picking representatives: it is not true that $b$ is not divisible by $5$ for $a/b \in S$, but only that every $x \in S$ can be written as $a/ b$ with $b$ not divisible by $5$. For example, $5/5 = 1/1 \in S$. Similarly when you take $a/b, c/d \in S$, it is not automatic that $b$ and $d$ are not divisible by $5$ but you can always assume that without changing the elements. It may be useful to note that if $a/b \in S$ *and* $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then $b$ is not divisible by $5$.

You should also check that $S$ is closed under $\frac{a}{b} \mapsto -\frac{a}{b}$ and maybe, depending on the definition of subring, that $1 \in S$, where $1 \in R$ is the multiplicative identity.